# Corruption When Taking a DB Dump

Tags: database, sybase, dump, corruption

Is it possible to have a corruption when taking a db dump from a sybase server when users are using the db at the same time?
Suppose i issued

```
dump database MyDB to "compress::MyDB.dmp"
```

The db size is large, therefore the dump may take several minutes to complete.
During the dump a user issued:

```
insert data into table X
insert data into table Y
```

So table X may already be dumped when new data is inserted in tables X and Y. Therefore the dump may contain the previous table X and the new table Y which is the corruption.
is this a possible scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple links for you to check out:

- http://www.sybaseteam.com/showthread.php?tid=506
- http://sybaseadmin.blogspot.com/2011/01/dump-database-three-phases.html

You should be able to run a sybase dump on a live database, even while inserts and updates are continuing. All changes should be synced at the very end of the dump for the most up-to-date changes.